# How best to look up objects by label?

Tags: java, model

I am writing the server backed by a pre-written API.  I'm going to get a number of strings representing ports, signals, paths, etc etc etc.  I need to look up the object associated with a given label, these objects are all in memory (no sql magic to do this for me).

My question is, how best do I associate a given unique label with the mutable object it represents?  I have enough objects that looking through every signal or every port to find the one that matches is possible, but may be slightly too slow.

To be honest the direct 'look at every object' method is probably good enough for so small a body of objects and anything else is premature optimization, but I still am curious what the proper solution would be if I thought my signals were going to grow a bit larger.  As I see it there are two options available.

First would be to to create a 'store' that is a simple map between object and label.  I could have it so that every time I call `addObject` the object is automatically saved into a hashmap or the like.  This works, but relies on my properly adding *and deleting* each object so the map doesn't grow indefinitely.  The biggest issue to me is that this involves having some hidden static map in my ModelObject class that just feels...wrong somehow.

The other option is to have some method that can interpret the labels.  All of these labels are derived from the underlying objects.  So I can look at the signal label, for instance, and say "these 20 characters are the port" to figure out what port I need.  This would allow me to quickly figure out what I need.  However, if the label method is changed the `translateLabelToObject` method needs to be updated as well or everything breaks.

Which solution is cleaner, or possibly a cleaner solution than either of above?

For the record I'm working with sufficient number of variables to make direct comparison a little slow, but not enough to be concerned about memory overhead, written in java.  All objects that have labels I need to look up extend the same parent class.

Comment: Everything your explaining is screaming `HashMap` to me, but without code it's hard to guarantee a correct answer. Try asking the question (with some code of course) at [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) to get a more definitive answer.

Comment: I know of a hashmap, if I stored a map between label and object it would be with a hashmap of course.  That is effectively option 1, the downside of said option being the use of a signle giant static object which hides the cability and well, static can be used in a negative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say "these objects are all in memory", see if LinkedHashMap with accessOrder=true is what you need.

Also if *ModelObject* doesn't seem like the right class then just make the right class to have this info: perhaps *ModelStore* (a singleton?)